I have an Admin Panel in my app from which I want to update user accounts in my firebase/firestore
So I have basically created a admin dashboard where I have a form, in this I can search user by his/her email ID. Once done the data is visible (first name, last name and role). I can then modify those fields and then hit update button. Once done what all changes i made in the form should reflect in the backend of my firebase/firestore.
Please find my code.
Note one more error I found was that eventough im trying to get the uid and putting in console.log .. i keep getting undefined in console.
import { collection, getDocs, query, where, doc, updateDoc, deleteDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { auth, db } from "./firebase";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

function UpdateUser() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});
    const [isEditable, setIsEditable] = useState(false);

    const handleSearch = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            const q = query(collection(db, "Users"), where("email", "==", email));
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);



            if (querySnapshot.empty) {
                toast.error("User not found!");
                return;
            }

            const userDoc = querySnapshot.docs[0];
            setUserData(userDoc.data());
            setIsEditable(true);


            console.log("Fetched user data:", userData);
            console.log(userDoc.data);
            const x = userData.uid;
            console.log(x);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching user:", error.message);
            toast.error("Error fetching user data!");
        }
    };

    const handleUpdate = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();


        if (!email) {
            console.error("Email cannot be empty.");
            toast.error("Error updating user: Email is required.");
            return;
        }

        try {

            const userRef = doc(db, "Users", userData.uid);
            await updateDoc(userRef, { ...userData, email });

            toast.success("User updated successfully!");
            setUserData({});
            setIsEditable(false);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error updating user:", error.message);
            toast.error("Error updating user data!");
        }
    };


    const handleDelete = async () => {
        if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user?")) {
            if (!userData.uid) {
                console.error("User data missing ID. Cannot delete.");
                toast.error("Error deleting user: User data incomplete.");
                return;
            }

            try {
                const userRef = doc(db, "Users", userData.uid);
                await deleteDoc(userRef);

                toast.success("User deleted successfully!");
                setUserData({});
                setIsEditable(false);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error deleting user:", error.message);
                toast.error("Error deleting user data!");
            }
        }
    };


    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSearch}>
            <h3>Update User</h3>

            <div className="mb-3">
                <label>Email address</label>
                <input
                    type="email"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Enter email"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}

                    required

                    disabled={isEditable}
                    style={{ marginBottom: "5px" }}
                />
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary ms-2">
                    Search
                </button>
            </div>

            {isEditable && (
                <>
                    <div className="mb-3">
                        <label>First name</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            placeholder="First name"
                            value={userData.firstName || ""}
                            onChange={(e) => setUserData({ ...userData, firstName: e.target.value })}
                            disabled={!isEditable}
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-3">
                        <label>Last name</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            placeholder="Last name"
                            value={userData.lastName || ""}
                            onChange={(e) => setUserData({
                                ...userData, lastName: e.target.value
                            })}
                            disabled={!isEditable}
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-3">
                        <label htmlFor="role">ROLE</label>
                        <select
                            id="role"
                            className="form-control"
                            value={userData.role || ""}
                            onChange={(e) => setUserData({ ...userData, role: e.target.value })}
                            disabled={!isEditable}
                        >
                            <option value="SME">SME</option>
                            <option value="Agent">Agent</option>
                            <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div className="d-grid">
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={handleUpdate} disabled={!isEditable}>
                            Update
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger ms-2" onClick={handleDelete} disabled={!isEditable}>
                            Delete
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </>
            )}
        </form>
    );
}

export default UpdateUser;

